# Woocommerce $_GET variable only returns $_GET['q'] - Ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

I'm working with a Woocommerce site that has an Ajax issue. Whenever I try to run a wc-ajax function I get a malformed json error or a full page reload inside a div.

I see that in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax the AJAX is defined by checking the $_GET variable for wc-ajax. The code looks like this:

```
add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'define_ajax' ), 0 );

public static function define_ajax() {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['wc-ajax'] ) ) {
        if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
            define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
        }
        if ( ! defined( 'WC_DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
            define( 'WC_DOING_AJAX', true );
        }
        // Turn off display_errors during AJAX events to prevent malformed JSON
        if ( ! WP_DEBUG || ( WP_DEBUG && ! WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY ) ) {
            @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
        }
        $GLOBALS['wpdb']->hide_errors();
    }
}
```

The url I'm sending the request is /checkout-2/?wc-ajax=update_order_review. So if I print out $_GET I would expect it to look like this:

```
$_GET['wc-ajax'] = "update_order_review"
```

However, I am getting this instead:

```
$_GET['q'] = "/checkout-2/?wc-ajax=update_order_review"
```

Has anyone come across something like this before or have any ideas what would change $_GET's default functionality? Or at least the default functionality as I understand it.

Thank you!